# Scroll position changes after sap.m.Table update

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am facing an issue with the scrollbar in `sap.m.Table`.

In short: when I try to enter the data up to 11th or 12th row, the scrollbar used to stay in the same position! But from the 13th row or more, when I try to enter the data, the scrollbar moves up every time and this frustrates the users!

I am using Object Page Layout with Icon Tab. Table in one tab and other Info on second tab.

[image: In 13th Line, scrollbar is down.]

Now when I enter the data, the scrollbar moves up:

[image: Scrollbar moved up after entering data.]

Comment: With which UI5 version is the app running? You can press [Ctrl] + [Shift] + [Left Alt] + [P] to find it out.

Comment: Hi Hoffmann, I am using 1.71 Version. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `growing="true"` to the Table to enable [Extended Change Detection](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/7cdff73f308b4b10bdf7d83b7aba72e7). If the model is a `JSONModel`, a `key` is also required in the aggregation binding info object:

```xml
<Table xmlns="sap.m"
  growing="true"
  items="{
    path: 'myModel>/myCollection',
    key: <property name of which values are unique. Only if myModel is NOT an ODataModel!>
  }">
```

The issue was most likely caused by rerendering the entire table: user enters data → The entered value gets stored in the model → Model notifies all its bindings to detect changes → The binding in the input field sees that its bound `value` has changed → The input field invalidates itself and instructs its parents to rerender too → The entire table gets rerendered (i.e. the old HTML element of the table gets replaced with a new HTML element) → Table has to reapply the focus → Didn't remember where the focus was set previously, so the first element of the table (here: table header) gets the focus. → Browser notices a focus change and changes the scroll position accordingly.

With `growing="true"`, the *Extended Change Detection* is enabled, which prevents rerendering the entire list control.

Comment: Hi Hoffman, I tried with the above property but unfortunatley still the same!May be Is there any property related to sap.m.listitem?

Comment: @RanjithRupireddy It's hard to tell from here without an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Or do you have a running sample where I can reproduce the issue? You can fork [this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/16J1TFICxbqETCzaxuZ0) and extend for example. The above answer gives a general explanation and usual fix for the unexpected but typical scroll behavior.

Comment: @RanjithRupireddy Are you using a `factory` function by any chance when creating the list items? Again, an mcve would help greatly here.